# Reentering Us with Visa Waiver after 2 months in Canada?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I know there are similar questions posted, but I need to ask because every question is different. The difference is, I think, the amount of time one can spend in Canada before going back to US. The US says it has to be a "relative amount of time" but no one knows how long. Maybe 2 months is a good time? According to experiences? Or the difference of entering by land with my own car?

We have been travelling with my husband on our camper van from Argentina all the way to Canda, I stayed in the US a 2months and a half and tried to renew the Visa Waiver by flying to Canada for the weekend to visit family (which of course I didn't know wasn't possible.) Immigration on the way back to the US wouldn't renew my 90 day stay, (they said unless I went back to my country of residence) so when I got to NYC we packed and left with our car before my time expired. So I left OK.

Now we have been in Canada for a month, and I intend to stay for one more month, but would like to get our car shipped home to Argentina from the US. By the time we leave, I will have stayed in Canada for 2 or 2 months and a half.

Do you think they will let me in the US to get to Baltimore to ship the car? We would have our plane tickets back of course and proof of the car shipment, but it seems like sometimes they don't care what you have, like they already have made their decision at the border. Should I stay longer?

Or, Plan B, would I be able to fly to Argentina with a stop in the US? (Because we fly with American Airlines.)

Comment: How is your question different from previous ones, e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/90-day-rule-on-the-us-visa-waiver-program-not-expiring-if-you-go-to-canada?rq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23820/transit-in-la-after-90-days-in-north-america-under-vwp-esta?lq=1?

Comment: I think the question @Annoyed linked clearly states that time spent in Canada counts INSIDE the 90 days. I do not understand what is not clear.

Comment: Where did you read about this “relative amount of time”? The amount of time is especially relevant for people who go *out* of North America (e.g. I stay 90 days in the US, fly to Brazil, when can I come back and start another 90-day period?) If you go to Canada, you still haven't ended your first stay as far as the US is concerned so wondering if you have been out of the US long enough does not seem to make sense. Staying longer in Canada does not help you *per se*, you need to be able to argue you left permanently (e.g. you reside there).

Comment: That's basically what Doc explained in his answer to the other question. It seems to me you already have an answer but you wish very hard your situation is different enough to spare you the need for a visa. It just isn't so, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry, didn't mean to annoy anybody, maybe you are right and it's hard for me to understand the way these rules are made. Didn't mean to take your time. Excuse my english and mistakes.